# Cargar una tabla con datos

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc

Trabajo en ASP.NET MVC 5 deseo poblar una tabla con datos que me trae una lista.

table HTML

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>ProveedorId</td>
        <td>Razón Social</td>
        <td>Documento Identidad</td>
        <td>Número documento</td>
        <td>Dirección</td>
        <td>Teléfono</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<ProveedorDto> list = SdProveedor.GetProveedor().ToList();
        return View(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando tengas pregunta así, agrega tu modelo para dar mejores respuestas :D

```
@model List<ProveedorDto>
<table class="table">
   <tr>
        <td>ProveedorId</td>
        <td>Razón Social</td>
        <td>Documento Identidad</td>
        <td>Número documento</td>
        <td>Dirección</td>
        <td>Teléfono</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>   
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>        
        <td>@item.ProveedorId</td>
        <td>@item.razonsocial</td>
        <td>@item.documentoDeIdentidad</td>
        <td>@item.numeroDeDocument</td>
        <td>@item.direccion</td>
        <td>@item.telefono</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo hice de la siguiente manera
Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<ProveedorDto> list = SdProveedor.GetProveedor().ToList();
        ViewBag.ListarProveedor = list;
        return View(list);
    }
```

View

```
<body>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>ProveedorId</td>
        <td>Razón Social</td>
        @*<td>Documento Identidad</td>*@
        <td>Número documento</td>
        <td>Dirección</td>
        <td>Teléfono</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var row in ViewBag.ListarProveedor)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@row.ProveedorId</td>
            <td>@row.RazonSocial</td>
            <td>@row.NumeroDocumento</td>
            <td>@row.Direccion</td>
            <td>@row.Telefono</td>
        </tr> 
    }
</table>
```

Comment: en ese caso, no tiene sentido que uses: return View(list); //ya que no usas el model de manera general, mejor dale: return View();

Comment: @fredyfx Tines toda la razón no es necesario poner el list dentro del View.

Answer (score 0):

para tu ejemplo si el modelo se llama Proveedor el codigo podria ser como el sigueinte:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Proveedor>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>ProveedorId</td>
        <td>Razón Social</td>
        <td>Documento Identidad</td>
        <td>Número documento</td>
        <td>Dirección</td>
        <td>Teléfono</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
        <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProveedorId)
        </td>
      <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.razonSocial)
        </td>
      <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.docId)
        </td>
      <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.numId)
        </td>
      <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.direccion)
        </td>
      <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.telefono)
        </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```